# Benefit of checking TCP port or UDP port

Tags: ports, network-scanners, tcp, udp

I'm studying port scanning. How can an attacker benefit from the information of checking TCP ports or UDP ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, packets sent to a closed port will either be rejected or ignored/dropped. Thus, if a port is closed, you will not be able to establish a connection or communicate with the device through that port. And if you can't easily communicate with the device, then needless to say it becomes much more difficult (though not necessarily impossible) to launch an attack.

With this in mind, port scans are a good starting place for an attacker for a few reasons, such as:

**They tell you which ports will actually accept traffic, so you don't waste time trying exploits on closed ports.** This one is pretty straightforward; it is usually much more difficult to launch an attack on a closed port barring a serious operating system or firewall vulnerability.

**They can hint at what services are running on the target computer.** 
There are standard port numbers for various protocols - for example, web traffic normally goes through port 80, encrypted web traffic normally goes through port 443, SSH graffic normally goes through port 22, and FTP traffic normally goes through port 21. So if you portscan a server and notice that only ports 80 and 22 are open, then you can infer that the machine is probably a web server and SSH server, and start by trying attacks that target HTTP and SSH.

Comment: most port scanners I use include the functionality to grab the banner in order to determine what service is running on the port